# Undefined reference to MIN

Tags: c, compilação

Ao compilar o meu programa de média com descarte, ocorre o seguinte erro. Lembrando que usei o `MIN` para descartar o menor valor entre a, b, c e d.

> Meu programa.c:(.text+0x8b): undefined reference to `MIN'
>   [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Segue abaixo o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
    float a, b, c, d, res;

    scanf("%f\n%f\n%f\n%f\n", &a, &b, &c, &d);

    res = (a+b+c+d)- MIN(a,b,c,d)/3;
    printf("%f", res);

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um problema bem óbvio é que você não está incluindo o arquivo que possui a definição de `MIN`. Mas isto não vai resolver o problema porque esta função (uma macro na verdade) só aceita dois argumentos sendo passados e você está passando quatro. Então teria que criar uma função própria para lidar com todos estes argumentos. Também há uma problema de fórmula, por isto coloquei parênteses no lugar certo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

float multiMin(int num, ...) {
    va_list lista;
    va_start(lista, num);
    float min = va_arg(lista, double);
    for (int i = 1; i < num; i++) {
        float item = va_arg(lista, double);
        if (item < min) min = item;
    }
    va_end(lista);
    return min;
}

int main(void) {
    float a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%f\n%f\n%f\n%f\n", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    printf("%f", (a + b + c + d - multiMin(4, a, b, c, d)) / 3);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/OndHbR). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/iztmmkcr-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57242/101).

Se não quiser criar uma função só pra isto pode fazer o seguinte:

```
int main(void) {
    float a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%f\n%f\n%f\n%f\n", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    printf("%f", (a + b + c + d - fmin(a, fmin(b, fmin(c, d)))) / 3);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Math/MultipleMin2.c).

Tem que incluir o *header* `<math.h>`.

Note que eu preferi usar a `fmin()` do que a macro `MIN`. Ela funcionará melhor. Não vejo motivos para uso da macro em compiladores modernos.

Comment: A ideia é muito interessante (va_arg, ...)+1; mas no meu caso não está a dar o resultado esperado. Propunha: `int multiMin(int num, ...)` e `multiMin(4,a,b,c,d)`

Comment: @JJoao eu tinha errado o tipo do retorno, na verdade a ideia é que funcionasse totalmente com `float`. Alguém deu -1, não sei se foi só por um detalhe desses. Se foi isso, está consertado, se for outra coisa, gostaria de saber o que está errado para eu poder consertar e não ficar informando coisa errada para todo mundo. Infelizmente não estou conseguindo ver mais problemas. Se for alguém que só negativou porque não gosta de mim, aí ninguém vai dizer nada e mesmo que eu resolva, não vai retirar o -1, porque a intenção era esta mesmo.

Comment: @bigown -1+1=8 ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Oops, ignorem esta resposta:** não tinha reparado mas a solução anterior já tinha uma variante
quase igual a esta...

E já agora uma solução atamancada e nada genérica,:

```
#define MIN2(x1,x2)        (x1 < x2 ? x1 : x2) 
#define MIN4(x1,x2,x3,x4)  MIN2( MIN2(x1,x2), MIN2(x3,x4))

#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float a, b, c, d;
    scanf("%f%f%f%f", &a, &b, &c, &d);
    printf("%f", (a + b + c + d - MIN4(a,b,c,d))/3);
    return 0;
}
```