# Como retornar um elemento específico dentro de um array?

Tags: c, array

Estou tentando retornar o maior entre 4 números, para isto to usando a função `qsort()` disponível no `<stdlib.h>`. Segue o código:

```
 int comparison (const void *a, const void *b){
        if (*(int*)a == (*(int*)b)){
            return 0;
        }
        if (*(int*)a > (*(int*)b)){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    int max_of_four(int a, int b, int c, int d){
        int vector[4] = {a, b, c, d};
        qsort(vector, 4, sizeof(int), comparison);
        return
    }

    int main() {
        int a, b, c, d;
        scanf("%d %d %d %d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
        int ans = max_of_four(a, b, c, d);
        printf("%d", ans);


        return 0;
    }
```

Tem um `return` em aberto ali, como eu faço para retornar o último elemento da minha *array* vector agora ordenado? Teria algum modo de fazer essa mesma função para um número ilimitado de números ao invés de 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria isto:

```
return vector[3];
```

que é o último elemento deste *array* (já que começa em 0).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/GetElement.c).

Se a quantidade for variável aí você terá que pegar a quantidade de itens constantes no vetor. Aí pode passar já um vetor ou uma lista de itens (raramente é uma boa). Se quiser receber uma lista variável de argumentos pode ver mais ou menos como fazer em [Função scanf com quantidade variável de parâmetros, como implementar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126395/101) ([mais um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/57242/101)).